# How many times is item in array?

Tags: ruby

```rb
arrays3=["rove","rouda","blue", "red","blue"]
def count_elements(arrays)
 arrays.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |total, e|  "#{total[e] += 1}" ; total

 }

end

count_elements(arrays3)
```

I need to have the return be: name: rove count:1 
I got: `{{:name=>"blake"}=>2, {:name=>"ashley"}=>1}`

Comment: `arrays3.count { |name| name == 'rove' } #=> 1` ?

Comment: What is the exacty syntax you'd like to have?

Comment: This is a duplicate. Answers anyway are: `arrays3.group_by(&:itself).map { |k,v| [k,v.size] }.to_h` or `arrays3.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }`

Comment: @sagarpandya82 `arrays3.count("rove")`

Comment: @steenslag pretty cool.

Comment: @EricDuminil yes I naturally veer toward `group_by` too. Though there's something quite elegant about updating a hash.